# Dynamics AX SSRS not showing recent data

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

i have an issue with a report in dynamics.
I have an invoice report (more specificly EInvoiceReport_MX), and im printing some variables, the problem is that the users sometimes, they edit the info of the CustInvoiceJour table, to show more information in the report, and when they go to the report and print in screen, the data edited is not showing, so we wait 'til the next day and the info is suddenly showed.
somebody knows how to fix this issue?

thanks
regards

Comment: Are you add new fields in report data source table to you in report layout?

Comment: nope, I just modified the information saved in the data dictionary tables, for example, an invoice direction, but the updated information is not showing, it just shows the old information

Comment: You may have to flush the cache in your code before running the report.
Did you try to restart the reporting services after modifying the data and before running the report to see if that helps?
What about flushing cache (server/client) before running the report?